# Kafka Connect cassandra source -error for Decimal data type

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, spark-structured-streaming

I am using kafka connect cassandra source connector 1.0 version. I have a decimal datatype column(price) in cassandra table and writing it to the kafka topic as json from source connector,it is writing the decimal value in some string format like like `"price":"AA=="`. 
Now it is giving error in my spark streaming while converting to float as "number format exception"....?? please suggest what may went wrong while writing the value in kafka topic.
Advance thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [known bug](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-cloud/issues/48) in Kafka Connect + Decimals. As proposed in the issue, you'll need to perform "manual" conversion of data from base64-encoded string into `BigDecimal`:

```
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(
    new  BigInteger(Base64.getDecoder().decode("BfXhAA==")), scale);
```

Answer (score 0):

In connector file surround field with to_char(fieldname)