# Kafka Connect Sink to Cassandra :: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type

Tags: cassandra, apache-kafka, datastax, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to setup a Kafka Connect Sink to collect data from a topic into a Cassandra Table using the Datastax connector : https://downloads.datastax.com/#akc

Running a standalone worker running directly on the broker, running Kafka 0.10.2.2-1 :

```html
name=dse-sink
connector.class=com.datastax.kafkaconnector.DseSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
datastax-java-driver.advanced.protocol.version = V4

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false

internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false

plugin.path=/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-dse/kafka-connect-dse-1.2.1.jar

topics=connect-test
contactPoints=172.16.0.48
loadBalancing.localDc=datacenter1
port=9042

ignoreErrors=true

topic.connect-test.cdrs.test.mapping= kafkakey=key, value=value
topic.connect-test.cdrs.test.consistencyLevel=LOCAL_QUORUM
```

But i have the following error :

```js
2019-12-23 16:58:43,165] ERROR Task dse-sink-0 threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder.streamFactory()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory; @7: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory' (from method signature)
  Current Frame:
    bci: @7
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder' }
    stack: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab4 0002 b600 08b0                    

 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper.builder(JsonMapper.java:114)
 at com.datastax.dsbulk.commons.codecs.json.JsonCodecUtils.getObjectMapper(JsonCodecUtils.java:36)
 at com.datastax.kafkaconnector.codecs.CodecSettings.init(CodecSettings.java:131)
 at com.datastax.kafkaconnector.state.LifeCycleManager.lambda$buildInstanceState$9(LifeCycleManager.java:423)
 at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
 at java.util.HashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1625)
 at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
 at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
 at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
 at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
 at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
 at com.datastax.kafkaconnector.state.LifeCycleManager.buildInstanceState(LifeCycleManager.java:457)
 at com.datastax.kafkaconnector.state.LifeCycleManager.lambda$startTask$0(LifeCycleManager.java:106)
 at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660)
 at com.datastax.kafkaconnector.state.LifeCycleManager.startTask(LifeCycleManager.java:101)
 at com.datastax.kafkaconnector.DseSinkTask.start(DseSinkTask.java:74)
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.initializeAndStart(WorkerSinkTask.java:244)
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:145)
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:139)
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:182)
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

No additional error on cassandra or Kafka side.
I see active connection on the cassandra node but nothing arrive in the Keyspace.

Any idea why ?

Comment: what is your table structure & schema for data inside the topic?

Comment: i'll gonna extract some field from a json payload. But even when i'm trying with a simple string payload in the topic, i have the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Imho this is a problem caused by use of the JSON internal converters with BigDecimal data ([see related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53390352/kafka-connect-cassandra-source-error-for-decimal-data-type)).  As described in [the following blog post](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/), the `internal.key.converter` and `internal.value.converter` are deprecated since Kafka 2.0, and shouldn't be explicitly set.  Can you comment out all `internal.` properties & re-try?

P.S. Also see how [JSON + Decimal has changed in Kafka 2.4](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-481%3A+SerDe+Improvements+for+Connect+Decimal+type+in+JSON)

Comment: If i do this, i have the following error :
"Missing required configuration "internal.key.converter" which has no default value."
(I'm using kafka 0.10.2.2-1 which apparently require a default value)